# Webpack not importing bootstrap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I have a webpack module federtaion micro frontend project. It was working fine until I have made some changes to my project and since then it doesnt even render andymore. I have even reverted my changes and it still doesnt render. I dont get any errors while compiling, no errors in the web console and after some testing I found out webpack doesnt even import my bootstrap for some reason and I dont know why.

This is my webpack.config.js:

```
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require("clean-webpack-plugin");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const ModuleFederationPlugin = require("webpack/lib/container/ModuleFederationPlugin");
const deps = require("./package.json").dependencies;

module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/index.js",
    mode: "development",
    devServer: {
        port: 1000,
    },
    output: {
        publicPath: "auto",
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".jsx", ".js", ".json"],
        fallback: { crypto: false },
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.m?js$/,
                enforce: "pre",
                use: ["source-map-loader"],
            },
            {
                test: /\.m?js/,
                type: "javascript/auto",
                resolve: {
                    fullySpecified: false,
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.(css|s[ac]ss)$/i,
                use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(ts|tsx|js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader",
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/i,
                type: "asset/resource",
            },
            {
                test: /.json$/i,
                type: "json",
            },
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProgressPlugin(),
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
        new ModuleFederationPlugin({
            name: "MainFrontend",
            filename: "remoteEntry.js",
            exposes: {
                // States
                "./Store/GeneralStore": "./src/store/general",
                "./Store/MainStore": "./src/store/main",
                "./Store/LicenseOverviewStore": "./src/store/LicenseOverview",
                "./Store/ManageUserStore": "./src/store/ManageUser",
                // Components
                "./Components/DataInteraction/PasswordEye":
                    "./src/components/DataInteraction/PasswordEye",
                "./Components/ErrorHandling/ErrorModal":
                    "./src/components/ErrorHandling/ErrorModal",
                "./Components/DataInteraction/SearchBar":
                    "./src/components/DataInteraction/SearchBar",
                "./Components/DataInteraction/NotifyPopUp":
                    "./src/components/DataInteraction/NotifyPopUp",
                "./Components/DataInteraction/Pagination":
                    "./src/components/DataInteraction/Pagination",
                "./Components/Loading": "./src/page/Loading",
                "./Components/DataInteraction/ItemsPerPage":
                    "./src/components/DataInteraction/ItemsPerPage",
                // Util
                "./constants": "./src/constants",
                "./Helpers": "./src/util/helpers",
                "./MobileSize": "./src/hooks/useMobileSize",
                "./makeRequest": "./src/util/makeRequest",
            },
            remotes: {
                MainFrontend:
                    "MainFrontend@http://localhost:1000/remoteEntry.js",
                ManageUsers: "ManageUsers@http://localhost:1001/remoteEntry.js",
                LicenseOverview:
                    "LicenseOverview@http://localhost:1002/remoteEntry.js",
            },
            shared: {
                ...deps,
                react: {
                    singleton: true,
                    requiredVersion: deps.react,
                },
                "react-dom": {
                    singleton: true,
                    requiredVersion: deps["react-dom"],
                },
            },
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: "./public/index.html",
        }),
    ],
};
```

This is my index.js:

```
console.log("Before importing");
import("./bootstrap.js");
console.log("After importing");
```

And this is my bootstrap.js:

```
console.log("Inside Bootstrap");
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import "semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css";

import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<App />);
```

All the console logs were not there before, I have added them and found out that both console logs from the index.js show up in the web console but the one inside the bootstrap doesnt. Again I do not get any errors or warning in the compiler terminal nor in the web console.